# What are Delay Signed Assemblies?

Tags: .net, signing

Probably a simple question.. but I don't know what it is...

Answer (score 11):

I found the answer [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/vandita/delaysignassemblies08022006120501PM/delaysignassemblies.aspx).

> Delay signing is a process of generating partial signature during development with access only to the public key. The private key can be stored securely and used to apply the final strong name signature just before shipping the project.

Answer (score 3):

Delayed signing refers to a technique of partially signing assemblies while they are in development. Signing an assembly basically certifies that assembly by the manufacturer and prevents tampering and hi-jacking of that assembly. The signing is accomplished by using public key/private key encoding of parts ...

Stolen from [here](http://209.85.173.132/search?q=cache:-H5VpMnTkJ8J:searchwindevelopment.techtarget.com/expert/KnowledgebaseAnswer/0,289625,sid8_gci996687,00.html+computer+dictionary+delay+sign&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us).

As I think your question was?